Help understanding why Module variables (e.g. esoteric) sometimes persist as scoped (esoteric$) in the name space, and sometimes not
This part will print the change:
nomos = Names["Global`*"];
Print @ Complement[Names["Global`*"],nomos];

And in between you can run one of three versions:
testing[]:= Module[{esoteric,var},esoteric={}];
testing[inEsoteric_]:= Module[{esoteric,var},esoteric={}];
testing[inVar_]:=Module[{esoteric,var},var={}];

Which will print out these results, respectively:
{esoteric, testing, var}
{esoteric, esoteric$, inEsoteric, testing, var, var$}
{esoteric, inVar, testing, var}

Questions:
Do you get the same print readout?
Why does the second example occur as it does?
Why does the third example occur differently than the second example?
